# HTML table- Create pop up box for each <td> and display xml data

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a project and I am trying to create a web application. So far, my code is like [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table). I press the button and a table appears. As you can see in the example, this table contains data of an XML file. **THE PROBLEM:** I want by clicking each 'td', a popup box to appear. This box will contain different data for each 'td', from the same XML file. Specifically, it will contain an image and some text that refers to the 'td'. Actually, I want something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2). I tried adding this code to my code and I created a popup button in every 'td'. But clicking these buttons, nothing happens. It would be nice if you share your knowledge with me!

Answer (score 0):

i think its help full for your logic.

```
  $('td').click(function () {
        $("#MyModal").modal("show");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a class to td , and by click of that id with jquery modle called by

`$("#MyModal").modal("show");`

checkout this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/shyam004/dhu66cb3/1/)

P.S. i have used bootstrap model for popup, but any other can be used with minimum change in code.